# I want it to open in an iframe in the same tab (same url) on prompt not new tab. im trying to make a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

```
 (function() {
    let url = prompt("what site do you want to open?");
  window.open(url,'_self');
    win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
    win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
 var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.border = 'none';
    iframe.style.width = '100%';
    iframe.style.height = '100%';
    iframe.style.margin = '0';
    iframe.src = url;
    
    win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```

here is my code, tell me what I did wrong. Also if you can, tell me how to get it to automatially put the https:// in the prompt

I have messed around and nothing worked